# Python-requests how to call js function to calculate some value before post?

Tags: python, python-requests

I use Requests (2.2.1) to login a url `http://tx3.netease.com/logging.php?action=login`, but the login logic of this url is different from Django's csrf token mechanism, that is:

1. When you GET this url, there is two import values `formhash` and `sts` in html text, both of which will be used in a js function `do_encrypt` (in file `http://tx3.netease.com/forumdata/cache/rsa/rsa_min.js`). This is fine, I can easily grab them via re.

The key part of html text is:

```
<form method="post" name="login" id="loginform" class="s_clear" onsubmit="do_encrypt('ori_password','password');pwdclear = 1;" action="logging.php?action=login&amp;loginsubmit=yes">
<input type="hidden" name="formhash" value="91e54489" />
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="http://tx3.netease.com/" />
<input type="hidden" name="sts" id="sts" value="1409414053" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" />
...
<input type="password" id="ori_password" name="ori_password" onfocus="clearpwd()" onkeypress="detectCapsLock(event, this)" size="36" class="txt" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" />
...
</form>
```

2. After entering email and original password `ori_password`, clicking submit button will call `do_encrypt`, which will use  `formhash`, `sts` and `ori_password` to set the real password `password` for the post dict. Problem comes out -- There seems no way to get `password` string directly. (For contrast, you can directly get `csrfmiddlewaretoken` from `session_client.cookies['csrftoken']` in Django case)

This is the code:

```
import requests
import json
import re

loginUrl = "http://tx3.netease.com/logging.php?action=login"

client = requests.session()

r = client.get(loginUrl)
r.encoding='gb18030'

stsPat = re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="sts" id="sts" value="(\d+?)" />')
formhashPat = re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="formhash" value="([\d\w]+?)" />')

sts = stsPat.search(r.text).groups()[0]
formhash = formhashPat.search(r.text).groups()[0]


loginData={
    'username'  : "smaller9@163.com",
    'password'  : ..., # Set by js function do_encrypt
    'referer':'/',
    'loginfield':'username',
    'ori_password':'', # it's `111111`, but `do_encrypt` will set it to empty.
    'loginsubmit':'true',
    'sts':sts,
    'formhash':formhash,
    }
# r = client.post(url=loginUrl,data=loginData)
```

Comment: You'll either have to execute the JS with a JS engine *or* reimplement the same logic in Python. Neither of which `requests` can help you with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have permission to do so, try logging in with `selenium` as i think that will be more inline with what you are ultimately trying to do.

```
from selenium import webdriver

USERNAME = "foo@bar.com"
PASSWORD = "superelite"

# create a driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# get the homepage
driver.get("http://tx3.netease.com/logging.php?action=login")

un_elm = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
pw_elm = driver.find_element_by_id("ori_password")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=loginsubmit]")

un_elm.send_keys(USERNAME)
pw_elm.send_keys(PASSWORD)

# click submit
submit.click()

# get the PHPSESSID cookie as that has your login data, if you want to use
# it elsewhere
# print driver.get_cookies():

# do something else ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your method helps me to successfully login! Now I will try to make it work with `Requests`'s session :-)